# IKImageView redraw problem on image change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, ikimageview

I have one large IKImageView in my window. The image changes when the user clicks something. When the change happens, the IKImageView first draws the background colour, then draws the image over the top of it, which looks pretty crappy. Is there a way to get it to switch images more smoothly?

It also contains garbage when the window loads for a split second until the image loads - is this related?

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved - stop using IKImageView and never bother with it again because it is poorly documented and buggy. Back to the trusty NSImageView. NSImageView refreshes in a much better way than IKImageView - IKImageView draws the whole background unbuffered, then draws the image unbuffered. NSImageView just does the whole thing as one operation.

NEVER DARKEN MY DOOR AGAIN, IKIMAGEVIEW.