# IKImageView resize problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ikimageview

I have an IKImageView that fills the entirety of a window. When the window is resized, the image does not resize with it. So I naturally think, well I'll change the zoom factor in the windowDidResize. However, the zoom does not adjust smoothly, it animates a zoom whenever the mouse cursor stops moving for an instant. I really want it to resize like NSImageView does. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Probably should have joined this with your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495868/ikimageview-redraw-problem-on-image-change

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - stop using IKImageView and never bother with it again because it is poorly documented and buggy. Back to the trusty NSImageView.